# dash delimiters in java are changing the output

Tags: java, arabic

I am using the following below java code to convert the numerics to arabic

```
    String str = "1234-5678-9101";

    char[] chars = {'٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'};
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            builder.append(Chars[(int)(str.charAt(i))-48]);
        } else {
            builder.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
```

the expected output is ٩١٠١-٥٦٧٨-١٢٣٤ but the result is ١٢٣٤-٥٦٧٨-٩١٠١ (reverse direction)

Comment: why do you subtract 48? `builder.append(Chars[(int)(str.charAt(i))-48]);`

Comment: @javapirate Because character '0' has decimal value of 48. This way you get number 0 for character '0'.

Comment: Any suggestions will be appreciated on how to solve this

Comment: Maybe this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255490/461499

Comment: @RobAu how to apply the same in the used `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, this issue was resolved using the below code:

```
String str = "1234-5678-9101";

char[] chars = {'٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
        builder.append(Chars[(int)(str.charAt(i))-48]);
    } else {
        builder.append("\u202A");
        builder.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: [This will be good reading for the future.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm)  Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The code works, that's obvious. But it looks to me that the dash character (`-`) is breaking the rules of Arabic writing from right to left - it seems that each group of numbers is correct but the overall order is not.

```
expected: ٩١٠١-٥٦٧٨-١٢٣٤
actual: ١٢٣٤-٥٦٧٨-٩١٠١
```

I can't help much more than this because that's all I know on Arabic alphabet. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's an answer that doesn't *quite* answer the question.  It would probably be better served as a comment instead.

Comment: Agreed. At that time I didn't know a comment can hold 600 characters and be styled. But it did help to solve the problem :)