# How to force JTable to NOT invert text in the case it contains arabic characters?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, arabic, idn

I have the following text:

*وزا.word*

But when displaying it on my JTable it looks like this:

*word.وزا*

In every JLabel or TextArea or any other input it does look like the original text:

*وزا.word*

ONLY on the JTable I am having such problem.

I do not care if it is making sense or not, and yes I know the Arabic Language is written from right to left. My guess is Java is detecting it and automatically inverting it, but I do not want it to.

Note: I have no idea what *وزا* means, and for practical purposes I don't care. It's also irrelevant for this case wether *وزا.word* does not make sense and *word.وزا* does or viceversa.

Note 2: The text, *reversed* or not is always aligned to the left (as I expect it to).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  I guess part of the problem is that it does not really make sense to mix both Left-to-Right & Right-to-Left text styles (guessing that is ..Arabic characters beside the English?).  Could you not represent one as a tool-tip?

Comment: I am curious to see the screen that shows the above description. Can u please share it.

Comment: Which Java version are you using. A JLabel should also render that string with the Latin characters to the left of the Arab word.

Comment: @jarnbjo that's what the OP says; the problem seems to be with `JTable`.

Comment: @fge: Perhaps even different browsers render his question differently. Here, his question reads that JTable renders the Latin word left of the Arab word, while JLabel and TextArea renders the Arab word left of the Latin word.

Comment: @jarnbjo same here; I don't believe browser rendering enters into account here (if it did I'd be surprised!)

Comment: *"(guessing that is ..Arabic.."*  (Note to self) 'Intuitively obvious' if you read either the title *or* the body.  :P

Comment: I forgot to mention it is JTable as a swing component, so yeah there are no browsers involved. I am using Java version 7 btw.

Comment: again for better help sooner, post an SSCCE, 1. there is one bug with one of Arabic glyphs, 2. maybe not related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a guess, your default `Locale` is giving the [default renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) a `ComponentOrientation` that is inconsistent with your other settings. You might try creating a [custom renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) having the preferred orientation using one of the approaches suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475320/230513).

Addendum: `java.text.Bidi` supports bidirectional reordering; you may be able to use unicode format control code points, as suggested in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6177294/230513).

Comment: I am currently attempting this at the moment, with no luck. Also, isn't the orientation more about the alignment of the text rather than the way it is printed? Wether وزا.word or word.وزا it is always aligned to the left (as I expect it to).

Comment: `java.text.Bidi` supports bidirectional reordering; IIRC, the tutorial example `TextComponentDemo` uses a `DocumentListener` to display some details; see also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6177294/230513)..

Comment: You should add this last comment as an answer...so I can mark it as solved because it did work!! Thank you very much trashgod. I'll await your specific reply to mark it as solved.

Comment: @GeorgeW: I am facing now the same problem, how can the solution you found? Could you please explain me?

Comment: @SagittariusA: Custom components are a very broad topic, and I'm not sure about the problem you are now facing. You might get more widespread attention if you were to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a question, perhaps citing the work mentioned here and adding a [mcve] showing your specific problem.

Comment: @trashgod thank you for your kind reply. Yesterday I forgot to link the question I posted, where you should find what you required  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515783/jtable-inverts-words-when-text-contains-mixed-arabic-and-western-characters