# JTable inverts words when text contains mixed arabic and western characters

Tags: java, swing, internationalization, jtable, arabic

I have already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597129/how-to-force-jtable-to-not-invert-text-in-the-case-it-contains-arabic-characters) but I am afraid it cannot help me, I do not know how to use `java.text.Bidi` and most of all if it is suitable for me.

We are providing Arabic language support for out project and in addition to providing the relative translated properties files, I am adapting all Java Swing components so that they can manage input with Arabic Locale (the writing from right to left). This is the instruction I am executing for each of them:

```
private static final ComponentOrientation arabicOrientation = ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(new Locale("ar"));
/* ... */
component.applyComponentOrientation(arabicOrientation);
```

This seems to work fine for each component but for JTables. In fact, if a cell has mixed characters/words and when cell stop editing, then the original input words order is not respected and western words are showed before Arabic ones. For example:

[image]

[image]

Is this a standard and righr behaviour of Swing? Is that supposed to be showed like that?

When language is changed by user into another one, this is what is performed:

```
private static void adjustLanguageSettings() throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, ParseException {
    //...
    if("japanese".equals(language) || "chinese".equals(language) || "arabic".equals(language)){
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(...); //Look and Feel with Dialog font
    } else {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(...); //Look anf Feel with Verdana font
    }

    //for instanc: language = LANGUAGE.JAPANESE("japanese","ja","JP") or ARABIC("arabic","ar","")
    if(language != null && LANGUAGE.lookUpByCode(language) != null){
        LANGUAGE i = LANGUAGE.lookUpByCode(language);
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale(i.getLanguage(),i.getCountry()));
        JFileChooser.setDefaultLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    }
}
```

So, the Locale should be Arabic everywhere.
Finally, here are some code snippets of our TableCellRendered and TableCellEditor:

```
public class DefaultLabelCellRender extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer, Serializable {

    protected ColumnProperties properties;

    private static final ComponentOrientation arabicOrientation = ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(new Locale("ar"));

    /* ... */

    public DefaultLabelCellRender(ColumnProperties properties) {
        super();
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(getNoFocusBorder());
        this.properties = properties;
    
        this.applyComponentOrientation(arabicOrientation);
    }

    /* ... */

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        /* ... */

       this.applyComponentOrientation(arabicOrientation);
       return this;
    }
}

public class DefaultTextEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor,Observer {

    private JTextField editor;

    /* ... */

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isselected, int row, int col) {


        /* ... */
        this.editor = new JTextField(3)
        /* ... */
    
        this.editor.setText(text);
        this.editor.applyComponentOrientation(arabicOrientation);

        return (this.editor);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm unsure from your fragment, but `UIManager` says "Once the look and feel has been changed it is imperative to invoke `updateUI` on all `JComponent`s." Also, a [mcve] may allow others to examine your result in a comparable environment.

Comment: @trashgod  sorry for the late, but I don’t understand what you mean. How can I call `updateUI` on my components? Why should I do that? I see that the problem is only in `JTable` rendeding, and not editing. I really don’t understand what you mean

Comment: Just guessing from your fragment; see also `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI`.