# Concat RTL string with LTR string in javascript

Tags: javascript, internationalization, right-to-left

I'm facing trouble in concatenating Arabic string with English string but their order is being messed!

I tried `+` operator and `str1.concat(..)` but nothing works for me.

```
var a = 'english'
var b = 'أ.ب-000082-13'
var c = '000004-ر خ-2014.xml'

//var myCoolString =a + '\\' + b + '\\' + c;

var myCoolString =a.concat("\\",b,"\\",c) 

document.getElementsByTagName('output')[0].innerHTML = myCoolString;
```

The result was like this: english\أ.ب-000082-13\000004-ر خ-2014.xml

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177294/string-concatenation-containing-arabic-and-western-characters .. however, are your numbers written LTR? you may find you have the direction changing within each string too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The characters your are looking for are [`\u202A`, `\u202B` and `\u202C`](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Directional_Formatting_Codes)

```
function wrap_dir(dir, str) {
    if (dir === 'rtl') return '\u202B' + str + '\u202C';
    return '\u202A' + str + '\u202C';
}


wrap_dir('ltr', a) + wrap_dir('ltr', '\\') + wrap_dir('rtl', b) + wrap_dir('ltr', '\\') + wrap_dir('ltr', c);
// "‪english‬‪\‬‫أ.ب-000082-13‬‪\‬‪000004-ر خ-2014.xml‬"
```

Not sure why `c` wanted to be *LTR*, maybe because it ends `.xml`?

Comment: Thanks Paul! I know this is an old thread and this answer works great but something I encountered that I would like to share with everyone. If anyone is planning to use the wrapped text in the browser URL make sure you escape the characters added in this function so it appears correctly. Thank you