# String concatenation is not working as expected for RTL languages

Tags: java

I tried to concatenate the strings but none of below things works for me in Arabic language and it works fine for all other languages.

1. Approach

   ```
   String fileName = getCurrentDate() + UNDERSCORE
       + getFileNameFromSubject(emailTO.getSubject()) + "."
       + emailDefinition.getEmailMessageFileType();
   ```
2. Approach

   ```
   StringBuilder fileName=new StringBuilder();
   fileName.append(getCurrentDate()).append(UNDERSCORE)
       .append(getFileNameFromSubject(emailTO.getSubject())).append(".")
       .append(emailDefinition.getEmailMessageFileType());
   ```
3. Approach

   ```
   String fileName=String.format("%s_%s.%s", getCurrentDate(),"subject",".msg");
   ```

Do we need to use any specific API to make it work for all languages including RTL languages?

Comment: I think you have to reverse concatenation order for Araibic.

Comment: Could you please add an example output? As expected

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177294/string-concatenation-containing-arabic-and-western-characters

Comment: You should provide a better problem description than “it does not work”. Further, when the code does not work, why do you tag the question with `[performance]`?

Comment: It creating text like this img src onerroralerthello hello.msg_20181128-113423-170 +0530 due to this file format type icon is showing incorrect .i e .msg extension changed here

Comment: This is hard to believe, as the definition of what is the extension of a file name string does not depend on the user language. Neither does the string concatenation. Even if a name might get rendered differently with RTL content, no file manager should consider the file type to be different. You should provide a [mcve] capable of reproducing the issue…